# How to select the even and first td of rows with attribute data-mainRow using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I tried this:

```
  $("#topTable tr[data-mainRow]").find("td:first:even").css("background-color","black");
```

This does not work because it hightlight all rows first td....

Comment: Looks right to me? Try setting up a quick example in jsFiddle !

Comment: Isn't what you are trying to do is to highlight even rows AND the first row. The selector would then be `.find("td:first, td:even")`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#topTable tr[data-mainRow]").find("td:even:first").css("background-color","black");
```

Comment: My logic was wrong. It should be: $("#topTable tr[data-mainRow]:even").find("td:first").css("background-color","black");